# How to avoid circular dependencies in validation module

Tags: python, validation, anti-patterns

I recently refactored my code to put input validation methods that are shared among several classes in their own module, `validate.py`. Some of these validation methods check if their input is an instance of a class, *e.g.* `MyClass`. Therefore `validate.py` must import `MyClass` so it's method `is_MyClass` can check if `isinstance(input, MyClass)`. But, I want to use some validation methods from `validate.py` in `MyClass` to sanitize input to `MyClass.my_method`, so `MyClass` must import `validate.py`.

Something tells me I just casually refactored my way into an anti-pattern. If what I'm trying to do implies circular dependencies, then I must be Doing It Wrong™.

But, code reuse is a good idea. So what's the best practice for sharing validation methods in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parts of the validation code that are specific to one of the classes should probably be put into the class itself - maybe as a classmethod? That way the 'generic' validation code can just call obj.validate() at the appropriate time. You then don't need to import the classes from the generic validation code.

Comment: Yup, that's what I figured. Thought there might be some super pythonic cool way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While Tom Dalton's answer is probably correct as far as the best design goes, it may be worth noting that import cycles often work just fine in Python.

The limitation though is that you need to use `import my_module` syntax and avoid top-level (global) code that uses the imported modules. Declaring functions (or classes with methods) that use the imported module is fine.

You usually run into trouble if you're using `from my_module import obj` or something similar, since this will only work if `obj` has already been defined in the other module. If that other module is in the process of importing your module, the class definition or global variable assignment may not have have happened yet.

So for your specific case, an alternative solution may be to have your `validate` module use `import my_class`, then `is_MyClass` can do `isinstance(input, my_class.MyClass)`.